# How can i select the top 5 records from a DataView which contains all records in descending order?

Tags: asp.net

This is my code:

```
DataSet dsCategoryRes = new DataSet();
dsCategoryRes = oCourse.SubscribedResources(Profile.UserName, CustomerId, "0", 0);
DataTable dt = dsCategoryRes.Tables[0];
DataView dv = new DataView(dt);


Int32 maxCnt;
if (dv.Table.Rows.Count <= 5)

    maxCnt = dv.Table.Rows.Count - 1;

else

    maxCnt = 4;
int cnt;
for (cnt = 0; cnt <= maxCnt; cnt++)
{

    dv.Sort = "CategoryName DESC";
    //dv.Table.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Take(5);

    dt = dv.ToTable();
    dt.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Take(5);
    rptSub.DataSource = dt;


    rptSub.DataBind();
}
```

Using this am to able to sort in descending order but i am not able to select the top 5 values.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int32));
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
//Creating some dummy data
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   var newRow = dt.NewRow();
   newRow["ID"] = i;
   newRow["Name"] = "dummyData" + i;
   dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
}

var dt2 = new DataTable();
dt2 = (from rows in dt.AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(x => x.Field<int>("ID")) select rows).Take(5).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: This should sort the original DataTable on the field "ID". It should then select the first five and then create a new datatable copy that you can set as the datasource directly or assign it to a different datatable as in the example